# Need Help with LaTeX: Can I Convert This Math Image?

Tags: graphs

I'm new to LaTeX and am attempting to convert my handwritten Math notes into a digital format. I have this specific graph (attached below) that I want to convert to LaTeX. Is it possible to do this conversion using LaTeX or some other tools? Should I invest time in learning LaTeX to achieve this, or are there existing tools or resources that could assist me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Depends on how many similar images you like to draw. For drawing in LaTeX exist may packages, for example `tikz`, `pstricks`, etc. For mentioned package you an find a lot examples on this site. Also exist home pages (for example https://texample.net//)  with collection of solutions. Drawing is not straightforward, you need to invest some times to learn this. But in documentation of mentioned packages exist tutorials, which can help you in learning proces.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the suggestions! I'll look into tikz, pstricks, and the tutorials you mentioned.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is it just about drawing graphs or do you also want to write text, papers, articles in addition? For this combination Latex is very suitable. If you only need the graph and maybe want to calculate different outcomes from your input directly, there may be more straightforward programming solutions like using **Python**-plotting or software like **SageMath** etc. I just recommend it because your question is a little bit unspecific concerning your concrete needs ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I need both graphs and text, so I’ll start learning Latex. Appreciate your guidance!

Comment: @VenkatKrishna,did you succeed? Kkindly check my answer below, e.g. showing some similar or different approaches. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a little late, but here's a kind of mini-tutorial for you. Some hints and comments.

#### 1. starting out

Well, it just draws the two vectors. Simple enough ...

#### 2. 1st refinement

Adds some styles, i.e. overwrites the standard arrow-tip, and defines `v2` for your 2nd vector. E.g. if you want to change its color, dash-pattern etc, just change the style here (which is more relevant for repeating parts, see below).

#### 3. adding a coordinate system for reference

Pretty straight forward. Kindly watch the various way to use and change styles.

- `\draw[cs] (-2, 0) -- (3,0);` just using `cs`
- `\draw[->]    (0, 0) -- (2,-1);` putting an arrow-tip
- `\draw[->,v2] (2,-1) -- (0, 3);` same AND using style `v2` at the same time

#### 4. refining labels, adding meander

If you followed so far, there are no surprises here, just more of what you want to display.

#### 5. adding notes

Finally adding your notes. Now this one is tricky for several reasons:

- I put the two nodes with text manually; usually you'd relate it to one of the previously drawn paths
- you can enter text in math-mode inside a nodes text
- if you'd use the ams-package(s), you could also enter a matrix environment, where I just tricked using a transposed vector
- you can rotate nodes, but, see above, placement requires trial and error this way
- for this purpose kindly note the polar coordinate used `(50:3.5)`, i.e. 50 deg counterclockwise, 3.5cm apart from center (0,0) , wrt the nodes center (!)
- there are several ways to introduce rotated braces, which I leave out here

[image: results]

```
% ~~~ standalone: good for development; loads tikz already as stated ~~~
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% provides nicer arrow-tips


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

 % ~~~ 1. starting out ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,-1);
    \draw[->] (2,-1) -- (0,3);  
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 
 % ~~~ 2. 1st refinement ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},%           changing arrow tips
    v2/.style={dashed},%    defining a style for the snd vector
 ]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,-1);
    \draw[->,v2] (2,-1) -- (0,3);   
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 
 % ~~~ 3. adding a coordinate system for reference ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},%           changing arrow tips
    v2/.style={dashed},%    defining a style for the snd vector
    cs/.style={black!50},%  styling the coordinate system
 ]
    % ~~~ coordinate system ~~~~~~~~ % <<< NEW
    \draw[cs] (-2, 0) -- (3,0);
    \draw[cs] ( 0,-2) -- (0,4); 
    %     putting some labels
    \node at (0,-1) {-1};   
    \node at (0, 3) { 3};   
    \node at (2, 0) { 2};   
    % ~~~ vectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->]    (0, 0) -- (2,-1);
    \draw[->,v2] (2,-1) -- (0, 3);  
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 
 % ~~~ 4. refining labels, adding meander ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},%               changing arrow tips
    v2/.style={dashed},%        defining a style for the snd vector
    cs/.style={black!50},%      styling the coordinate system
    ly/.style={xshift=-2mm},%   shifting labels at y-axis
    lx/.style={yshift=-2mm},%   same for x-axis
    me/.style={dotted},%        styling the meandering path
 ]
    % ~~~ coordinate system ~~~~~~~~
    \draw[cs] (-2, 0) -- (3,0);
    \draw[cs] ( 0,-2) -- (0,4); 
    %     putting some labels
    \node[ly] at (0,-1) {-1};   
    \node[ly] at (0, 3) { 3};   
    \node[lx] at (2, 0) { 2};   
    % ~~~ meander ~~~~~~~~~~~~ % <<< NEW
    \draw[me] (2,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1,1) -- (0,1);
    %     and some labels there
    \node[lx,blue]  at (1.5,-1) {-1};
    \node[lx,blue]  at (0.5,+1) {-1};
    \node[ly,red] at (.9,.3) {+2};
    % ~~~ vectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->]    (0, 0) -- (2,-1);
    \draw[->,v2] (2,-1) -- (0, 3); 
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
    
 % ~~~ 5. adding notes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},%               changing arrow tips
    v2/.style={dashed},%        defining a style for the snd vector
    cs/.style={black!50},%      styling the coordinate system
    ly/.style={xshift=-2mm},%   shifting labels at y-axis
    lx/.style={yshift=-2mm},%   same for x-axis
    me/.style={dotted},%        styling the meandering path
 ]
    % ~~~ coordinate system ~~~~~~~~
    \draw[cs] (-2, 0) -- (3,0);
    \draw[cs] ( 0,-2) -- (0,4); 
    %     putting some labels
    \node[ly] at (0,-1) {-1};   
    \node[ly] at (0, 3) { 3};   
    \node[lx] at (2, 0) { 2};   
    % ~~~ meander ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[me] (2,-1) -- (1,-1) -- (1,1) -- (0,1);
    %     and some labels there
    \node[lx,blue]  at (1.5,-1) {-1};
    \node[lx,blue]  at (0.5,+1) {-1};
    \node[ly,red] at (.9,.3) {+2};
    % ~~~ vectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->]    (0, 0) -- (2,-1);
    \draw[->,v2] (2,-1) -- (0, 3);
    
    % ~~~ notes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ % <<< NEW
    \node at (3.5,-1.5) {$col_1 = [2, -1]^T$};
    \node[rotate=30] at (50:3.5) {some part of $col_2$};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non-LaTeX solution I would suggest drawing images like this in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). If you want you can the export them as PDFs to include as floats in a LaTeX document.